# programme complies without printing results in python

Tags: python

Whenever I compile this program it doesn't show me any print result. Can someone please tell me whats wrong is with this.Secondly I want to know that genfrom txt command is dealing with the data written in the file or is it doing something with the name of the file that is check1.0 and check1.5.

```
`path="folder"
datafiles=os.listdir(path)
prefix='check'  
dicdata={}
for df in datafiles:
    if re.match(prefix,df) and os.path.isfile(df):
        print ("df values are %s" % df)

        hmax=locale.atof(df[5:])   
        print ("hmax values are %s"% hmax)
        data=genfromtxt(df, delimiter=', ')
        print data
        dicdata[hmax]=data
        print dictData
       print len(data[0])
```

Comment: We cannot see what `datafiles` gives or your `genfromtxt` function... Try printing anything outside of the for loop

Comment: `print(df)` in the loop and you'll see its just the file name, not the path.

Comment: Include the function genfromtxt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the CWD (Current Working Directory) which may differ with the location of the files you're listing:

```
#/usr/bin/python

import os
import re

path="/home/mortiz/Documents/projects"
datafiles=os.listdir(path)
prefix='check'
dicdata={}
for df in datafiles:
#    print df
    if re.match(prefix,df) and os.path.isfile(path+'/'+df):
 #           print ("df values are %s % df")
            print df
```

Giving the absolute path of the file to your function in the condition **os.path.isfile()** , then that will return True and the code will be executed as you expect.

```
os.path.isfile(path+'/'+df)
```

genfromtxt is a function, not a command and you didn't provide it in your question, there's no way to tell you what is it doing without seeing its content.

Comment: `os.listdir` lists all of the contents of the directory. Files, subdirectories, links, special files.

Comment: True @tdelaney. fixing my answer because I've tested part of the script and the behaviour isn't what I've expected.

Comment: How I can check the dimensions of the data? because  without knowing dimensions i can't proceed in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` lists the contents of the directory but not the path needed to use them. You need to prepend `path` first. Since that changes what your regex is looking for, you can do the tests in two steps

```
path="folder"
datafiles=os.listdir(path)
prefix='check'  
dicdata={}
for df in datafiles:
    if re.match(prefix,df):
        df = os.path.join(path, df)
        if os.path.isfile(df):
            print ("df values are %s" % df)
            hmax=locale.atof(df[5:])   
            print ("hmax values are %s"% hmax)
            data=genfromtxt(df, delimiter=', ')
            print data
            dicdata[hmax]=data
            print dictData
            print len(data[0])
```

Comment: True, I've realized it after you mentioned what the function does, tested again and it was obvious :)

Comment: I have tried the above code but it is giving ValueError: could not convert string to float: r/check1.5

Comment: I have fixed the value error but when I print data it gives me [nan nan]. I want to know that will genfromtxt function show the result separating the values by , in the files named check1.0, check 1.5